# Raw Data provides date with "X" in front of it. ex "X1.22.20"

Tags: r, date

Here are the libraries I use

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

I bring in the data I am trying to analyze

```
url_in<-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/"
file_names<- c("time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv", 
               "time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv", 
               "time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv", 
               "time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv", 
               "time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv")
urls<-str_c(url_in, file_names)
```

I name the data

```
global_cases<-read_csv(urls[2])
global_deaths <- read_csv(urls[4])
US_cases <- read.csv(urls[1])
US_deaths <- read.csv(urls[3])
```

Then, after using pivot longer to allow the date to be a variable, I want to change the date to format MDY however, the raw data has the date with an X in front of it. So when I run mutate, I get a warning that says
"Problem while computing `date = mdy(date)`.
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. "

And then it replaces every date in the column with an NA

```
US_cases <- US_cases %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c('UID':'Combined_Key'),
               names_to = "date",
               values_to = "cases") %>%
  select(Admin2:cases) %>%
  mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>%
  select(-c(Lat, Long_))
```

Any idea how to handle this X in front of all these dates?

Comment: `...mutate(date = mdy(gsub("X", "", date)) %>%...` This will use a base R function to remove each X from the date column before the `mdy` function is applied.

Comment: Presumably the issue is that the CSVs have columns that start with numbers but those are generally not syntactic in R and may be loaded with some sort of adjustment like a leading X. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html

Comment: Check out the `check.names` parameter in `read.csv` (and maybe make sure to match up with what you set in  `name_repair` parameter in read_csv if you intend to join those names at some point).